# Problem in configuring opencv 2.2 on windows 7 (64-bit):

Tags: visual-studio-2010, opencv

I have windows 7 (64-bit) and I am trying to configure opencv 2.2 for Microsoft visual studio 2010, I followed the instructions given in the book  [OpenCV 2 Computer Vision Application Programming Cookbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1849513244) , but it’s not working, I performed the following steps:

1. Compile opencv 2.2 using cmake,  (source code: C:/OpenCV-2.2.0, where to build binaries: C:/OpenCV-2.2.0/build)
2. Open OpenCV.sln (which is made as a result of compiling by cmake in the folder C:\OpenCV-2.2.0\build), this is opened in visual studio, I build it (result of build: no errors, few warnings).
3. Add new property sheet to my project, and in VC++ directories, under the “Include Directories “ I give the path of C:\OpenCV-2.2.0\include\opencv and under the “Library Directories” I give the path of my lib files i.e C:\OpenCV-2.2.0\build\lib\Debug.
4. Within the linker tab under the Input, included the following Additional dependencies:

   opencv_core220d.lib

   opencv_highgui220d.lib

   opencv_features2d220d.lib

   opencv_calib3d220d.lib

According to the instructions on the book now everything should be configured correctly, but when I include header files,(after typing (Hash)include (angle bracket)) the intellisense only gives:

```
#include <cxcore.h>
#include <cv.h>
```

but instead it should had displayed

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
```

and when I write

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
```

it gives me error cannot open source file
    “opencv2/core/core.hpp“ , 
if I include

```
#include <cv.h >
```

I got 11 errors:

```
1.  IntelliSense: cannot open source file "opencv2/core/core_c.h"   c:\opencv-    2.2.0\include\opencv\cv.h 63  1   

2.  IntelliSense: cannot open source file "opencv2/core/core.hpp"   c:\opencv-2.2.0\include\opencv\cv.h 64  1   

3.  IntelliSense: cannot open source file "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc_c.h" c:\opencv-2.2.0\include\opencv\cv.h 65  1   

4.  IntelliSense: cannot open source file "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp" c:\opencv-2.2.0\include\opencv\cv.h 66  1
```

[The remaining errors are similar to the above errors.]

I have not included anything under the C/C++ -> General -> Additional Include Directories
in the property sheet, is there any need to include anything there ???

Can anybody please tell me, what I did wrong in the configuring process?

Is there any guide available specifically for configuring opencv 2.2 on windows 7 (64-bit) on visual studio 2010?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maximus solution sounds like a spray and pray attempt.

I cleanly only added [opencvDir]\include to my visual studio includes and it all worked really fine. 
Including with your syntax

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
```

works just fine, thats how i do it. The rest of the steps I did was exactly what you described, except that I have different projects with different parallel opencv installations, so i did not add OpenCV to my global environment variable "PATH" but rather than that I selectively use OpenCV for each project by selection Project Properies (right click project, select properties) => Debugging => "Environment" : Set to PATH=$(SolutionDir)Dependencies\opencv2.2\x86\bin" (in my case), and "merge environment" to "yes"

That is necessary so opencv finds its DLLs in case you link non-static.

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 1):

You need two include directories. For me it was, C:\OpenCV2.2\include and C:\OpenCV2.2\include\opencv

Comment: dookehster, thanks for reply, i added C:\OpenCV2.2\include in the include directories, now the intellisense is giving #include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>, but when i add this line, visual studio gives me 14 errors, 

 1 IntelliSense: cannot open source file "opencv2/core/core_c.h" c:\opencv-2.2.0\include\opencv2\opencv.hpp 46 1

 2 IntelliSense: cannot open source file "opencv2/core/core.hpp" c:\opencv-2.2.0\include\opencv2\opencv.hpp 47 1 
and 12 more similar errors, why is it unable to open the source file??

Answer (score 0):

Try including all directories in C:\opencv-2.2.0\modules\module_name\include
For example in your case it could be
C:\opencv-2.2.0\modules\core\include\
C:\opencv-2.2.0\modules\imgproc\include\
and many more. You should use comand line to get that list of directories in the C:\opencv-2.2.0\modules. And after each add include. 
I don't know why does this happens..

Answer (score 0):

In my property page,
in C/C++ -> Addictional Include Directory
I was using "%OPENCV_DIR\build\include"
Replacing by the real path fixed the issue with intellisense:
"C:\opencv\build\include"

I am running opencv 2.4.2 and Visual Studio 2010 SP1.